# Failed to sign APK package. (Unity 2017.2.0f3)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, package, apk, signing

I have made a huge research for resolving this problem and there are two topics just like mine in unity answers but these two can't also resolve my problem. I tried to set Build System to Gradle, updated sdk, downgraded sdk also did the same for jdk, changed tools folder, put some folders from build-tools to tools I even researched problem as a java error but NO! non of them has resolved my problem. That's why I'm opening a new question for this issue. Hope somebody can help.

Here it's shortcut of my error log:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to sign APK package.
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\apksigner.bat 
sign --ks "C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/Unity 
Projects/ProjectBattleRite/user.keystore" --ks-pass stdin  --ks-key-alias 
"lunatogi" --key-pass stdin  "C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Unity 
Projects\ProjectBattleRite\Temp/StagingArea/Package.apk"

stderr[
Error: keywords 'java|openjdk version' not found in 'picked up 
java_tool_options: -df'
Error: keywords 'java|openjdk version' not found in 'picked up 
java_tool_options: -df'
Error: keywords 'java|openjdk version' not found in 'picked up 
java_tool_options: -df'
Error: keywords 'java|openjdk version' not found in 'picked up 
java_tool_options: -df'
Failed to load signer "signer #1"
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(Unknown 
Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the same problem just repeating my keystore pass in Build Settings       ->Player Settings-> Publishing Settings block. Even if all password fields filled correctly, just remove them and fill again. But i have to do it every build.

Comment: Sorry for being really late but for the people who face that kind of problem, thanks for the answer I also resolved the problem in a way like this.